# Java Rest API to connect to Sharepoint

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, soap, java-http-client

I am trying to connect to Sharepoint using java of my web application.
I don't want to use Jshare or java-sharepoint as they are not in my organisations repository.
If anyone has done it previously without them please share the code snippets or any links that will be helpful.

Comment: What aspect of doing this are you having problems with?

Comment: How do I connect and download files from SharePoint? Same way I connect to other websites?